# Unable to close the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening the window by using

```
var childWindow = window.open('test.php','test',attributes);
```

In test.php I have a form to insert the data, onclick to submit button this window should be closed.
For this  I am writing `window.close();` on click to submit button but I am unable to close the window.
Please help me out ..

Thanks.

Comment: `childWindow.close()`

Comment: I have tried but i am unable to do so. Opening a window code in other page and submit button in other page so how it get to know when should i have to close.

Comment: After processing the data on the server side redirct to a page called `close.html` or something and the only thing the page does is `window.close()`. I have used this method before.

Comment: Or instead of creating a new window for form submission you could look into using a webservice to submit your data then no need to create another window to submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

So if you **open** a window:

```
window.open("test.php", "test");
```

you can **close** that window:

```
window.close("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN :

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open][1]

```
How do I know whether a window I opened is still open?


 You can test for the existence of the window object reference which 
is the returned value in case of success of the window.open() 
call and then verify that windowObjectReference.closed 
return value is false.
```

Hence in your main window from where pop-up opens - Run a setInterval function to detect whether windowObjectReference.closed returns false

```
var myOpenWindow=window.open(...)
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (myOpenWindow == null || myOpenWindow.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                //do something
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }, "seconds to poll");
```

Comment: this part will work when window is closed manually, i need to close the browser window automatically when user click the submit button.

Comment: @Sikander did you try redirecting to `close.html` page after form submission?

Comment: why don't u call window.close() on submit ?

Comment: yes I am redirecting to close.html but I am unable to close the window, have written the same stuff.

Comment: I have called the window.close() on submit, its closed the content and open the fresh window...